# Select data from different tables - vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to select some datas from my database and display it into the textboxes. First is i'm selecting the data from realestate.useraccounts and then to realestate.userprofiles. Its working on the useraccounts but not on the userprofiles.
`

```
    Try
        con.Open()
        Dim q1 As String
        q1 = "select userid,email from realestate.useraccounts where username='" & frmLogin.txtUsername.Text & "'"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(q1, con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.HasRows Then
            dr.Read()
            lblUserid.Text = dr("userid")
            txtEmail.Text = dr("email")
        End If
        con.Close()
        con.Open()
            Dim q2 As String
            q2 = "select * from realestate.userprofiles where userid = '" & lblUserid.Text & "'"
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(q2, con)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If dr.HasRows Then
                dr.Read()
                txtFirst.Text = dr("lastname")
                txtLast.Text = dr("firstname")
                txtAddress.Text = dr("address")
            End If
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Dispose()
    End Try`
```

Comment: In what way is it failing?  Describe the problem.

Comment: Why are you using 2 queries to do this? Clearly you are joining these tables on `userid`. Save yourself the hassle of opening a connection twice and rewrite your SQL as one statement.

Comment: Also; parametise your queries.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()` in the second one, so your dr.Read cant read on your second query.

You may also close your reader after use use it.

Let's try this:

```
Try
        con.Open()
        Dim q1 As String
        q1 = "select userid,email from realestate.useraccounts where username='" & frmLogin.txtUsername.Text & "'"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(q1, con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.HasRows Then
            dr.Read()
            lblUserid.Text = dr("userid")
            txtEmail.Text = dr("email")
        End If
        dr.Close()
        con.Close()
        con.Open()
            Dim q2 As String
            q2 = "select * from realestate.userprofiles where userid = '" & lblUserid.Text & "'"
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(q2, con)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If dr.HasRows Then
                dr.Read()
                txtFirst.Text = dr("lastname")
                txtLast.Text = dr("firstname")
                txtAddress.Text = dr("address")
            End If
            dr.Close()
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Dispose()
    End Try`
```

Comment: You have a good eyes on that mate. Its working now. Thanks alot!